# How can I get every first letter of my strings using jquery?

Tags: jquery

For example : 
Middle Name is Dela Cruz

and i need output like.

Middle Initial: DC.

Thanks  for response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: Split the name by space: `"Dela Cruz".split(" ");`, then do
`jQuery.map(["Dela", "Cruz"], function(name, i) {
  return name[0];
}).join("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex.

```js
var MName = "Dela Cruz";
var reg = MName.match(/\b(\w)/g);  
var result = reg.join(''); 
console.log(result );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str="Dela Cruz";
var output="";
$(str.split(' ')).each(function(){
    output+=this[0];
});
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are too lazy I guess. its really straight forward anyways

you can use charAt(0); to get first char of string

```
var name = "Dela Cruz";
var splitName = name .split(" ");
var initial = "";
for(var i=0; i <splitName .length; i++ ){
    var eachData = splitName[i];
    initial += eachData.charAt(0);
}

console.log(initial);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str="Dela Cruz";
var Res="";
$(str.split(' ')).each(function(key,value){
    Res+=value.charAt(0);
});
console.log(Res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringArray = "Dela Cruz".split(" ");
firstLetters = ""
for(i=0;i< stringArray.length; i++){
    firstLetters = firstLetters + stringArray[i].charAt(0);
}
console.log(firstLetters);
```

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined**

Comment: Remove `a` and added `stringArray` @Abhi

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.